# how to get file name and line number using git blame for any revision

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am trying to get checked in file name and its line number using git show but it is giving me whole file contents added/removed.

Is there any git command like svn blame to get file name and line number for an specific revision?

Answer (score 0):

`git show --name-only`

or simpler form

`git show --name-only --oneline`

Comment: Thanks Paul, but it gives me file name for any particular revision if mentioned but not giving me line numbers as well changed with that revisions